# Unable to Add Office 365 email into my Outlook 2016

Tags: office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am able to add my eMail account to a newly install Outlook 2016 in an entirely new PC.

But when I add the same account to my existing Outlook 2016. This was what happened.

1. File -> Add Account

[image]

2. By right, it should prompt the OAuth2 Sign on page. But it shows this page instead.

[image]

3. I chose Microsoft 365, and it ended in this page

[image]

I can't use POP3 nor IMAP as well. Seems like they had been disabled by MS.

Comment: Found my answer here: https://repairit.wondershare.com/email-repair/fix-outlook-encrypted-connection-is-not-available.html#:~:text=It's%20possible%20that%20the%20PST,to%20repair%20the%20PST%20file.

Answer (score 0):

I created a profile from the control panel, and then connected to my 365account, and it worked.

More details for your reference in [this article](https://windowsreport.com/outlook-something-went-wrong/#:%7E:text=How%20can%20I%20fix%20the%20Something%20went%20wrong,antivirus%20...%205%205.%20Run%20the%20troubleshooter%20).

Hope that may help you!

Comment: Thanks @Faery but I can't get mine working, either the profile or regedit.

Comment: Recent official documentation mentions this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/outlook-issues/outlook-cannot-setup-microsoft-365-account Hope that can help you!